# Assign value from filename and content of file to a template using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

In my directory path\, I have many text files with name something like this

```
area1.txt
area2.txt
area3.txt
```

Each file contains lots of one liner string that looks like this

```
user1
user2
user3
```

How do I write a Powershell script to pass all of the filename and content of file to a template so it will look like this for every iteration or combining all result in single file.

```
area "filename"
user "user1"
realname "user1"
```

Managed to write a script but it does not produce the desired outcome. Somehow it only produce last value of filename in loop and empty string after user and realname template.

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem path\ -Filter *.txt){
$result = @"
area $($file.BaseName)
area {0} 
realname {0} 
"@
}

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem path\ -Filter *.txt){
    foreach ($line in $file |Get-Content){
        $result -f $_
    }
  }
```

Need your help to point out the error in my script and help me to fix it. I really appreciate it if anyone can help.

Comment: modify your question: Copy and paste that contains user and realname and everything in-between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a single set of (nested) loops for this, then reference `$line` and `$file` appropriately inside the inner loop:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem path\ -Filter *.txt){
    foreach ($line in $file |Get-Content){
        @"
area {1}
user {0} 
realname {0}
"@ -f $line,$file.BaseName
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you sir but user and realname still returning empty string like my previous script :(

Comment: @wdzww my apologies, you need to reference `$line` to get the indiviual line of text